# creating model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This the schema design from my mysql table, I am trying to migrate to mongodb and I am using [mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) , I am confuse of the datatype to use in creating model for my locators table or collection... I am still new on this mongodb hope you can help me. or is it okay in mongoose to use model without declaring datatype ?

like this

```
var locatorModel = new Schema({});
```

Thank you in advance.

```
    CREATE TABLE `locators` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mch_id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
    `lat` DOUBLE(10,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lng` DOUBLE(10,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `latcot` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ttime` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tdatetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `velo` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `locators_mch_id_tdatetime_index` (`mch_id`, `tdatetime`),
    INDEX `locators_created_at_index` (`created_at`)
)
```

Comment: There are many way to migrate from mysql to mongo try check https://github.com/lovette/mysql-to-mongo http://mongify.com/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: @Michelem, can I ask some help please if I will create model for the locators what datatatype should I use because mongoose has no char,time and decimal ?

Comment: @Michelem, since mongodb is schemaless so it is okay to use model without specifying datatype only like this `var locatorModel = new Schema({});`

Comment: Char Is String time is Date and decimal is Double

Comment: @Michelem, thank you  for the reply. can I also put length in datatype in mongoose  model ? like string(1) for char(1) in mysql ? ...or it doesn't matter this in mongoose ?